# Email sending using SMTP not working with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I'm trying to send email using SMTP in asp.net. Following code is not working.

```
public string send_email(string name, string email, string message)
{
    var fromAddress = email;
    var toAddress = "ashish_sharma307@hotmail.com";
    string subject = "Feedback";
    string body = "From: " + name+ "\n";
    body += "Email: " + email + "\n";
    body += "Subject: " + subject + "\n";
    body += "Question: \n" + message + "\n";
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
    }
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);


    return "Your query has been submitted.";
}
```

This is not working as per expected. I'm trying to send an email from feedback form.

Comment: It worked after I added 
`{smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";smtp.Port = 587;smtp.EnableSsl = true;smtp.DeliveryMethod =System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail", "mypassword");smtp.Timeout = 20000;}`
Ain't there other process to push email without needing from email and password while sending?

Comment: do you want anybody to send email from your account? If not then ofcourse credentials are required.

Comment: what you can do, is setup SMTP on the server, and send through local host. google iis smtp. Once you have done that you need to setup SFR records for the emailing domain and add your server to it so emails sent do not get put in spam. that way you can send without username and password. the SMTP server can be set to only accept emails from the localmachine.

Comment: I just need to send mail from a email address that has been entered in feedback form in email section and i just want to define to which email the message from feedback is to be sent. I want no intermediate emails and credentials. [i.e. just message from and to, similar like mail() function in php]

Comment: @SmithMart, can you please show some codes. I do have access to my web server. I can implement it live or locally.

Comment: Link: http://forums.iis.net/p/1157046/1901343.aspx - This is how to setup smtp, should get you on the right track. But, you may run into trouble with spam filters if you try and send emails as someone else. google SPF Records to learn more about why the spam filter will likely eat it up.

Comment: Thank you @SmithMart. And with the same above code that i'v mentioned in my comment, is it possible to send email to some private domains like info@companyname.com or something like that. I tried, couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in an answer so it's easier to read.

In answer to your comments, here is the mail message i would send through a server with no credentials.

You can send emails from any address to anyone.

But, remember that the emails getting to where it's going is not guaranteed. mail filters will often reject emails that come from an smtp server that has not been added to the SPF record for that domain.

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();

m.From = new MailAddress("Smith@MyDomain.com");
m.To.Add(new MailAddress("someone@TheirCompany.com));
m.Subject = "Message from Smith";
m.Body = "Hello, Test Message";
SendEmail(m);

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
Host = "localhost",
Port = 25,
UseDefaultCredentials = false,                    
};

smtp.Send(m);
```

This is for sending through the local machine assuming you have setup an SMTP server.

There are so many variables and options for sending emails, and each one has it's own limitations.

Options

1. Setup and run your own SMTP server
2. Use a 3rd party to send emails such as [Campain Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com) - There are other providers
3. If you are sending from your company domain only, and they have Exchange email, use that server

Comment: that threw a long exceptional error! something like `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25............`

Comment: That error is because the localhost is not running an smtp server or it is running one, but it's being blocked by a firewall. make sure you have an smtp server running on the same machine

Comment: Both the `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` instances should be in `using` blocks.